# How to use RocksDB after installation? How to read from RocksDB from KSQL?

Tags: ksqldb, rocksdb

I have installed RocksDB using the command "sudo apt-get install librocksdb-dev". How can I use the DB? How can I read and write data using KSQL?

Answer (score 0):

What is it you're trying to do?

KSQL is part of Confluent Platform, built on top of Kafka Streams which uses RocksDB under the covers. 
You don't interface with RocksDB directly through KSQL, it is abstracted.

To get started with KSQL see https://www.confluent.io/ksql

Comment: I need to store some custom data in RocksDB and need to do some lookup against that data using a UDF function.